# Whats wrong in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

```
ALTER TABLE Physician 
Modify (RefLastName nvarchar(500),
RefFirstName nvarchar(500));
```

Getting Incorrect syntax error...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  I don't know what version you're using but I don't think Modify is a valid option see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The way you use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) is not like `CREATE TABLE`. You mention changes to the table elements rather than specifying all columns from scratch. Like:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD LastName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding columns or changing the size?

You might first try looking up alter table in BOL and then come back here if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you changing the size? If so, this is enough:

`ALTER TABLE Physician ALTER COLUMN RefLastName nvarchar(500)`

`GO`

`ALTER TABLE Physician ALTER COLUMN RefLastName nvarchar(500)`

`GO`

(You may need to force a rebuild of indexes.)

Comment: Yes I am trying to change the column size from c# code using SqlCommand.

Comment: Oke. My problem is i am updating column size using c# code. If i use above statement without Go Statment, SqlCommand (cmd.ExuecteNonQuery) updates the column size but returns -1. If i use Go Statment, it gives Incorrect Syntax near 'Go'.  I dont know if you can help me about this using c# code. If you want i can paste my c# code as well.

Comment: It's OK that ExecuteNonQuery returns -1.  That's normal. From MSDN: "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. [...] For all other types of statements, the return value is -1."

Comment: Why are you using C# code? This only needs to be run once, unless you're writing a utility to update a database. "GO" has no place in SQL queries run programmatically; it's to tell the SQL interpreter that the next query has nothing to do with the one above it.

Instead of using "GO" you should issue two separate queries, one per column.

Answer (score 0):

What is your syntax error ?

I looked at http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php

Maybe try with:

```
ALTER TABLE Physician 
Modify (RefLastName varchar2(500),
        RefFirstName varchar2(500));
```

Comment: Looks like oracle syntax...he didn't specify the server type

Comment: No actually i have no problem updating size of column using ALter Table and Alter column statment directly in MSSMS. But i am trying to update multiple columns using c# code (SqlCommand).